# Authentication filter is not getting called

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-filter

I have created one class `AuthenticationFilter` which extends `GenericFilterBean`. I have added this one in security config but when I am trying to login this filter is not getting called and control is directly going to `UserDetailsService`.

```java
@Configuration
@Order(ManagementServerProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${nwook.login.credentials.type}")
    private String credentialsTypeHeaderName;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/changePassword/**", "/uniqueCode/verify/mobile/**", "/signup/**",
                        "/uniqueCode/generate/**", "/uploadverificationdoc/**", "/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui",
                        "/swagger-resources", "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**",
                        "/validateSignup/**", "/socialLinks/**", "/socialLogin", "/configuration/*", "/swagger",
                        "/webjars/", "/v2/*", "/", "/css/", "/js/", "/img/*", "/vendor/*", "/swagger-resources*",
                        "/favicon*", "/swagger-resources/configuration/*", "/*.html", "/signup/**", "/verify/**",
                        "*.js")
                .and().ignoring().antMatchers("/login/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/secure/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("AUTHENTICATED_USER")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout/**")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
            .headers()
                .frameOptions().disable()
                .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterAfter(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), credentialsTypeHeaderName),
                BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(domainUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider())
                .authenticationProvider(otpAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider domainUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new DomainUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider otpAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new OTPAuthenticationProvider();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new CustomMD5PasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new CustomUserDetailsService();

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Bean
        public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
            JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
            KeyPair keyPair = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource("keystore.jks"), "foobar".toCharArray())
                    .getKeyPair("test");
            converter.setKeyPair(keyPair);
            return converter;
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory().withClient("acme").secret("acmesecret")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token", "password").scopes("openid")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(31536000).authorities("ROLE_AUTHENTICATED_USER").autoApprove(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).accessTokenConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
            oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Url : "/oauth/token"

Comment: Why do you think your custom filter should be applied, if you add the filter to the wrong configuration? URL `/oauth/token` is handled by `OAuth2Config`.